# Changing a Universal Windows app to function as a game

Tags: game-development, xbox

I have a standard Universal Windows app that is actually a game in a WebView container (because HTML5) and I was wondering if there's any way to change something in the files of my project so that it's actually treated as a game (and likewise would be installed as such when deployed to Xbox One, Series X etc.) Obviously I want to get rid of the "change input mode" dialog as well or else I can't map the menu button for a pause function or anything else for which one would do so (and yes, that includes "Konami Code" implementations).

UPDATE 2020-09-16: This ended up being a duplicate question. Refer to the link in the information bar for what ultimately did the trick.

UPDATE 2020-10-21: I totally forgot to inform the mods of the duplication in prior discourse. This has now been addressed and the answer is noted above. I have also removed the link and description from the post to clean things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things since I opened this question which require my immediate request to close it to further discussion:

1. It turned out that the game type change is automatic once in the store, and
2. It also ended up being a duplicate question (for which the link is now in the information bar).